# Wiring diagram of aller retour switch with lamp

Tags: wiring

I need to connect a lamp with 2 aller retour switches. In the wiring diagram how many cables will i have between the switches if the lamp is between them?

Comment: What is an "aller retour" switch?

Comment: A pair of switches that control the same lamp. You can switch on the lamp from the first switch and switch it off from the second switch.

Comment: In English, they are called “3-way switches”. This has been answered many times on diy.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Where is your power source? switch or lamp?  is there any existing 3 wire cable (+gnd)?   ( in EE lingo we call the switches 1P2T or SPDT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually if you´re using a three-way you´ll use 1 cable as the hot line, coming from the circuit breaker. This cable gets to the central screw of one of the switches. Done that, 2 wires will leave that switch and meet the other one. Finally, this other switch takes the last wire to the lamp. So counting on the neutral cable, you´d have 1+2+1+1 = 5 wires. If you want to count the earth one it would be 6.

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways to hook them up. (Thanks to Janka for the third)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSCABv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fopaID.png)</sup>

The first or third methods are the preferred ones. As Dave points out, the second leaves the light itself hot half the time and is prone to make before break switch shorting.

Comment: Is that second one code-compliant? It works, but it leaves you with no well-defined "line" and "neutral" at the lamp fixture.

Comment: There's a third method: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparwechselschaltung

Comment: @DaveTweed true, it is also susceptible to make before break issues.

Comment: @Janka isn't that the same as #1 here just drawn differently.

Comment: No, it's different, it has the common contacts of the switches connected and saves you one wire.

Comment: If you'd need an English name for it, I recommend *German Rollercoaster*. It's pretty popular over here.

Comment: Thanks for the add @Janka that one was new to me :D

Comment: @Trev option 2) is less desireable as it can switch Neutral whereas All 3 of Dave's switch Hot (Line)

Answer (score 3):

With SPDT ("three-way" in English) switches, you can't put the load (the lamp) between the switches, at least not electrically. If you want to "fold" the wiring so that the lamp is *physically* between the switches, you'll have to run extra wires from one of the switches to the load. This does not affect the number of wires "between the switches".

Normal arrangement:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3dHzn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Folded arrangement:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzQSln.png)</sup>

Funky German arrangement:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLmyf3.png)</sup>

Note that the last one requires 4 wires in at least one of the cables, more than either of the other arrangements. It also runs the lamp current through the largest number of wires. I fail to see any advantage to this, other than the fact that in the region between the two switches, you can connect both switched and unswitched loads.

Comment: That's exactly the idea, being able to connect the lamps and unswitched sockets everywhere with only four wires instead of five. If you don't need that feature, the number of wires needed reduce to three (move the lamp left.)

Comment: @Janka: I still don't see it. Look at my middle diagram -- you never need more than 4 wires in any given cable to put more lamps between the two switches. When do you need 5?

Comment: In your middle diagram, if you had a lamp connected at each switch, you already needed a four wires cable. But at the same time, you don't have L at the far end so if you also wanted an outlet, you needed a fifth wire. The third arrangement gives you both with only four wires.

Comment: @Janka: OK, but nobody said anything about having an unswitched outlet, which is outside the scope of this question. Furthermore, you wouldn't ordinarily put outlets and lighting (especially permanently wired lighting) on the same circuit anyway.

Comment: Originally, I only mentioned that arrangement for completeness. Mixing permanent wired lighting and outlets in one circuit is pretty common in homes over here, only office and factory buildings have them separated.